# Handling screen orientation while passing Extras from intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

This question may have been asked many times. Sorry ,but I'm a newbie and couldn't find an appropriate answer for my difficulty.

I have an activity say 'first' containing of a listview, which displays some list items. My next Activity, say 'second' which extends a fragment. I pass one string parameter to the fragment.
What i wan to do is, the clicked item from 'first' should be passed to the 'second'. this data i set as a string parameter to my fragment. I am able to achieve all this. 
But, the problem is, When i click item from 'first' and rotate my screen, MY APPLICATION CRASHES.
i tried writing this to my 'second' activity.

```
Stringvalue;
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle onOrientChange) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(onOrientChange);
onOrientChange.putString("myValue", value);  
}
```

and restore it ,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle onOrientChange) {
if (onOrientChange!= null){
value = onOrientChange.getString("myValue");
}
}
```

Why exactly is my app crashing?
How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: What does the logcat say? What is the exact error?

Comment: @Byron It gives me a NullPointerException there.

Comment: 1) always add annotation @Override when overriding a method, 2) this code looks OK so the NPE might be from other codes?! check line number and make sure it points you there...

Comment: @Yazan. Thanks for guiding me. I knew where i went wrong. I got to know after i had a close look at the errors and the line numbers that is seen in the logcat. Being new to android, i could not make out for errors due to super fast processing of logcats! Thanks anyways..

Comment: you can add filters for logcat, with appID (package name) so you can see logs from specific app only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("myValue", value);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    value = savedInstanceState.getString("myValue");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!this works.. Just had to check in onRestoreInsatnceState whether my list was null. if(List!=null)
            {
     fnDisplayList();
            }